# Iterate through nested objects and indexed Arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following structure:

```
0: {
        fulfilled: true
        pending: false
        rejected: false
        data: {
          0: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          1: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          2: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          3: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          4: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:40:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          5: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:50:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          6: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          7: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          8: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          9: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
        }
     },
1: {
        fulfilled: true
        pending: false
        rejected: false
        data: {
          0: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          1: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          2: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          3: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          4: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:40:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          5: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:50:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          6: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          7: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          8: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
          9: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
        }
     }
```

I need to iterate through data and its values.

I tried like this:

```
const data = Object.keys(items).map(key => items[key].data);
```

but this returns me this value:

```
0: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
1: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
2: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
3: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
4: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:40:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
5: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 01:50:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
6: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
7: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:10:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
8: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:20:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
9: {dateTime: Mon Feb 17 2020 02:30:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), position: Position, address: Address}
```

Comment: What's the expected output? That looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you have your data to iterate through it just use a `for` loop:

```
const data = Object.keys(items).map(key => items[key].data).flat();
for (item of data) {
    // Do your stuff
}
```